# AsyncTask onPost Execute is running but doInBackground is not

Tags: java, android, xml, debugging, android-asynctask

i have a problem. I am developing an android app, and in my activity i am using asyncTask. I am calling the task from my onCreate and updating my UI in onPostExecute. I have a listView and in the asyncTask i'm executing Http request to get info from server. But my problem is that sometimes while running the activity I don't get any output.

I tried debugging, and it seems that i am getting an a print from onPostExecute but none from doInBackground. I am also using Google Cloud Endpoints for Http request if it is relevant.

Please help.

Here's my Class :

```
public class ILiked extends CustomFragment {
public ArrayList<User> ilikedList = new ArrayList<>();
ListView userList;
MyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_iliked, null);
    ILikedAsyncTask task = new ILikedAsyncTask();
    task.execute(new Pair<>(getShared().getString("username", ""), v));
    return v;
}

public SharedPreferences getShared() {
    SharedPreferences shared;
    if (Login.sharedPreferences != null) {
        shared = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Login.MyPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    } else {
        shared = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Signup.MyPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    return shared;
}

public class ILikedAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<String, View>, Void, ArrayList<User>> {
    private UserApi myApiService = null;
    View context;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("I AM IN PRE EXECUTE");
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<User> doInBackground(Pair<String, View>... params) {
        context = params[0].second;
        if (myApiService == null) {  
            UserApi.Builder builder = new UserApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)

                    .setRootUrl("MYURL")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                        }
                    });

            myApiService = builder.build();
        }

        ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String username = params[0].first;
            UserCollection users = myApiService.getUsersILiked(username).execute();
            System.out.println("CONTENT" + users.getItems().toString());
            if (users != null) {
                List<User> userList = users.getItems();
                list.addAll(userList);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return list;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<User> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        userList = (ListView) context.findViewById(R.id.iliked_list);

        adapter = new MyAdapter(context.getContext(), result);
        userList.setAdapter(adapter);
        //System.out.println("List Content: "+result.get(0));
        userList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Profile fr = new Profile();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("username", result.get(position).getUsername());
                fr.setArguments(args);
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);
                ft.commit();

            }
        });
        System.out.println("DID THE ASYNC");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Might be a possibility that you are getting exception . Add a log in `catch block` to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just simple some **IOException** is thrown by **myApiService**.
You catch **IOExceptions** but do not print any log or stacktrace. Let's 
check first this one.

```
 catch (IOException e) {

        }
```

If you have logs from **onPostExecute** every time, so **doInBackground** was called 
for sure(Android does that).

Anyway you should remove all of this

> ```
>     userList = (ListView) context.findViewById(R.id.iliked_list);
>
>     adapter = new MyAdapter(context.getContext(), result);
>     userList.setAdapter(adapter);
>     //System.out.println("List Content: "+result.get(0));
>     userList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
>             Profile fr = new Profile();
>             FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
>             FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
>             Bundle args = new Bundle();
>             args.putString("username", result.get(position).getUsername());
>             fr.setArguments(args);
>             ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);
>             ft.commit();
>
>         }
>     });
> ```

from onPostExecute and do initialization in onCreate or other part of the code. In onPostExecute you should only update needed UI elements, notifyAdapters etc. Initialization should be done earlier. Consider that approach.

Comment: Thank you lots man, my api method was sometimes throwing an exception, handled it thanks.